# parser exception for extract in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract year part from date using extract in spark sql

```
     spark.sql("select extract(year from datecol) as dt from temp").show(false)
```

I am getting below exception for this.

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:missing ')' at 'from'(line 1, pos 20)
```

Comment: just use `select year(datecol) as dt`

Comment: which Spark version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

`extract(field FROM source) - Extracts a part of the date/timestamp or interval source`

This function available spark version `3.0.0` & lower version of spark it is not available hence you will get below exception if use `extract` function.

```
scala> spark.sql("select extract(year from datecol) as dt from tmp").show(false)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'from' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 20)

== SQL ==
select extract(year from datecol) as dt from temp
--------------------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
  ... 50 elided
```

Use `year` function.

```
spark.sql("select year(datecol) as dt from tmp").show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use year function to extract year from date.
For instance, if your date is in format 21-04-17 :

```
df1.withColumn("year", year(to_timestamp($"datecol", "yy-MM-dd")))
```